# exact answer for “what is j2ee?” - job interview

Tags: java, interview, java-ee

I'd like to ask if someone of you knows the exact meaning of JEE.

That's because a collegue of mine was asked this question in a job interview, and was "unable to answer properly"... to speak with his interwiewer's words. And when he told me what he said to his interviewer I got really surprised, since it was more or less what I would have answered myself - in a concise form, the first paragraph of [this](http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/J2EE) article.

> J2EE (Java 2 Platform, Enterprise Edition) is a Java platform designed for the mainframe-scale computing typical of large enterprises. Sun Microsystems (together with industry partners such as IBM) designed J2EE to simplify application development in a thin client tiered environment. J2EE simplifies application development and decreases the need for programming and programmer training by creating standardized, reusable modular components and by enabling the tier to handle many aspects of programming automatically.

That seems not to be enough, since the interviewer asked for "more precise and less general definition".

Is there really a more precise definition for JEE? Or did my colleague just find the fussiest-interviewer-ever? :)

Comment: It's more currently called "JavaEE", since we're long past the "Java 2 Platform" days.

Comment: I know, but in my country it's sometimes still called "j2ee"... especially by aged interviewers, it seems. :)

Comment: Who cares what the exact official definition is? So long as you can talk about JEE and what kind of things are in it, then this should be enough.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First I would have corrected the interviewer by telling him, that since version 5 it's named JavaEE.

Further I would have detailed the parts that make up JavaEE, e.g. JPA, JSF, JSP, etc...

Comment: +1 The interviewer was probably expecting what components made up J2EE/JEE.  A good Q would be about his/her use of J2EE, indicates an org using old tech...

Comment: yeah correcting the interviewer on a spelling/minor mistake is bound to go down well.

Comment: I agree that specific components should be mentioned, otherwise it sounds like a generic advertising that tells how wonderful a technology is but does not tell what it does. It reminds me of that joke, when a little boy wants to buy a menstrual pad because the ad says you can "practice sports, feel free and unworried" while wearing it.

Comment: @NimChimpsky if my future employer can't stand correction.  Perhaps I will be happier else where.

Answer (score 0):

Just say that it's a set of APIs or technologies that allows you to build secure, scalable and distributed systems. Then maybe start talking about what those are from servlets, to jsp, ORM, EJBs etc. then talk about the various frameworks. Maybe you can also say that institutions such as banks like it because it's open source, it has an established market and there are a lot of experienced developers who know it.

I'm assuming he/she just wanted a less "rigorous" definition of what JEE is.